# Lose all Kue/Redis Jobs when Node restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, jobs

I'm looking through some of the options for implementing a job queue in Node and chanced upon Kue which uses Redis.

Is it true that because the jobs are stored in Redis, if I were to restart Node or the server, all the jobs will be lost?

Comment: Redis is a persistent store, so you should be able to restart your Node app or the server and not lose the queued jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis is in-memory persistent store. It stores data in key-value pairs after certain amount of time as configured in conf file. So, your data, that is comitted, will be persistent even if server or node goes down or is restarted.